# 403 forbidden on svn parent path

Tags: svn

Im trying to access the parent path for subversion on my browser. I go to `http://serverip/svn` and it says `forbidden`, however if i go to `http://serverip/svn/svnproject`, it shows the svn repo. How do I enable viewing the parent path?

Comment: Please, show config of subversion Location

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that you used `SVNParentPath` to configure the parent path, you can use `SVNListParentPath On` to enable directory browsing at that location.